# How to get rows data from a QTableWidget Column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

How can I get the value of each row from a specific column in a QTableWidget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the values of all the rows of a given column then you must iterate by obtaining the QTableWidgetItems using the item() method, verify if it is valid and then get the text.

```
col = ...

data = []
for row in range(tablewidget.rowCount()):
    it = tablewidget.item(row, col)
    text = it.text() if it is not None else ""
    data.append(text)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the data from each cell of the Table Widget by accessing it by iterating it through each row and column *( which can be done by ranging `rowCount()` each row & range of `columnCount()` per each column )* using the `item()` method.

If you're trying to access another widget from the Table widget's cell, then it is best to use `cellWidget()`, as it is specially made to access the widget present within the cell of the given table widget.

In the following case, I have assumed that the cell may contain item *(like some text)*. So, I have used the `item()` method instead of `cellWidget()`. In both of these methods, if there's no content within the cell, they return `None`. And lastly, I have appended the text to the data list that store all the content of the Table widget.

```py
data = []
for row in range(tablewidget.rowCount()):
    for col in range(tablewidget.columnCount())
        item = tablewidget.item(row,col)
        if item == None:
            continue
        data.append(text)
print(data)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).